# Error rendering images with nextJS. Image does not appear

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to render an image with nextJS, but it's not working. I can access this image via the browser URL, but the img component does not render it.

```
<img src="/public/images/logo.svg" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reference to static files inside `public` directory with just `/`.

```
<img src="/images/logo.svg" />
```

[Static File Serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
first import the image using below code.

`import logo from '/images/logo.svg'`

then add  the image using following code.

`<Image src={logo} alt=' ' width={100} height={100}/>`

Comment: This works for me, while putting the same address directly into the element doesn't work. Why?